# How to switch between Bootstrap tab panes with duplicate IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have two tab controls in my page with tab panes having the same ID. When I switch tabs in the 2nd control, the content does not update and still shows the last selected pane's. I've read somewhere that Bootstrap handles the switching thru IDs (which must be unique) for it to work, but my use case having duplicate ID is inevitable.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab1" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab2" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact2" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is a sample screenshot of the initial display:

[image]

The Home tabs have the same ID. When I select Contact tab in the 2nd group then switch to Home tab, the content is still for Contact.

[image]

Is there a way in jQuery or JavaScript that will allow me to show the correct tab thru onclick? Something similar to this:

```
$('#myTab2 a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
```

Comment: you can't have duplicated id's in HTML - I mean jQuery will let you target it (as will native querySelector) but just don't do it

Comment: use css class instead of Id

Answer (score 0):

Use **class** instead of id, targeting id using javascript or jquery will only get you the first instance i.e. the first element having that id.